# Strange Visual Studio 2013 errors

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, runtime-error

I'm experiencing the following Visual Studio 2013 error in the next picture whenever I want to add a project reference:

[image: Visual Studio 2013 issue]

This file exists in my hard disk.

Also, if I try to use a code snippet I get the following error:

[image]

For now, I've tried to reinstall Visual Studio 2013 and executing `devenv /resetsettings` command but it couldn't solve the whole problems.

Does someone experienced these errors and could solve them?

Comment: Try uninstalling and deleting vs2013 manually from registry

Comment: @Gilad And lose 3 hours again... grr!

Comment: it worked for me because the uninstaller didn't work well. but i can't make sure it will work for you.

Comment: don't kill me if it doesn't work... :)

Comment: @Gilad I'm the Terminator

Comment: @Gilad I've found what caused the problem! I'm going to post it.

Comment: @Gilad Terminator has disabled his mission: you can continue with your life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What caused the problem? Believe it or not, it was that I had Team Explorer 2013 installed before I decided to install Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

I did a trial-error uninstalling Team Explorer 2013, I rebooted my machine and bingo! This solved the whole problem...